# when click the button change the button value, that time don't load user detail in profile page from mongodb datase

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my profile page code

```html
  <div

      <% if (typeof usersArray !== 'undefined' && usersArray.length > 0) {%>

        <%for (var i = 0; i < usersArray.length; i++) { %>

          <div>
            1.<b>User ID:</b> <%= usersArray[i]._id%><br>
            2.<b>User Name:</b><%= usersArray[i].user_name%><br>
            3.<b>User NIC:</b><%= usersArray[i].uer_nic %><br>
            4.<b>User Address:</b><%= usersArray[i].user_address %><br>
            5.<b>User WorkExperience:</b><%= usersArray[i].user_WorkExperience %><br>
            6.<b>User Phone:</b><%= usersArray[i].user_phone%><br>
            7.<b>User Age:</b><%= usersArray[i].user_age%><br>
            8.<b>User Bio:</b><%= usersArray[i].user_bio%><br>
           9.<b>User Jop:</b><%= usersArray[i].user_job%><br>
        <center><button type="button"> apply </button></center>
        </div>

        <%}%>
      <% } %>

  </div>
```

I have store users details in mongoDb database.And I got users details in profile page from MongoDB database and I have users details on my profile page with the button. now I click the apply button that time change the button value as applied. same time users details don't load in profile page or hide.so how to do that?

This is my profile page
[image]

Comment: Can you show handler for `apply` button?

Comment: how to do that?..